# Laravel PHP: how to join each element of collection after update?

Tags: php, laravel

I have Clients collection in Laravel. `$clients = Client::all();`

I need to update it with a user's name for each item inside a collection. 
This is my code:

```
$clients = Client::all();

$clients->each(function ($item, $key) {

    if ($item->user()->first()) 
    {
        $user = $item->user()->first();
        $name = $user->name;
    } else $name = '';

    $client = collect($item);
    $client = $client->union(['user' => $name]);
});
```

The question is what is a proper way to form `$clients Collection` with $client updated.

So I need to `return $clients` whith user name included.

Models:

```
 // Client Model

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

// User Model
public function clients()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Client');
}
```

Migration:

```
Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->char('name', 200)->nullable();
$table->char('city', 100)->nullable();
$table->char('type', 20)->nullable();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
$table->timestamps();
$table->softDeletes();
```

Comment: How you have defined the relationship? one to many? please update your question with models and migrations

Comment: @SalmanZafar I have updated a question with models and migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below:

```
$clients = Client::all();

$clients->each(function ($item, $key) {

    $name = $item->user ? $item->user->name : "";
    return $name; // will append name in this client collection

});

return $clients
```

To read more about [each method visit](http://laravel-school.com/posts/how-to-use-each-function-in-laravel-48)

Hope it helps.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your support. A good reading, thank you for shared. 
Unfortunately, your code doesn't work as I needed. My code is forming a proper collection, I only don't know how to combine it back to a full collection. 
Yours code creates separate variable as relationships where place an User collection with all User data (all the fields of the model, not only name as I need).

Comment: ok. may be creating a eloquent resource? that would be easy though

Comment: yes, I try to do so. Thank you, appreciate your support!

Comment: read about it here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources

Comment: I have finally used a transform() function.

$clients->transform(function ($item, $key) {

    $name = $item->user ? $item->user->name : "";
    $item->name = $name; 
    return $item; 

});
 
Once again, thank you for your support!

Comment: Thanks. Happy to help